# Sum from date to date

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a table with this data:

```
Date        Value
...
2020-07-30  0.0
2020-07-31  12527.922
2020-08-01  29983.598
2020-08-02  34333.74
2020-08-03  33550.0
...
2020-08-30  22722.02
2020-08-31  21376.416
2020-09-01  23762.43
2020-09-02  16267.47
2020-09-03  25241.0
...
```

I need to sum from the first day of month to the next first day of month *inclusive*. Ie, from 2020-08-01 to 2020-09-01 inclusive and that value being in a column for all the days of the starting period (in this case 08) Any ideas? Thanks.

Expected output:

```
Date        Value      Period_Sum
...
2020-07-30  0          sum of 2020-07-01 to 2020-08-01
2020-07-31  1          ...
2020-08-01  2          sum of 2020-08-01 to 2020-09-01
2020-08-02  3          ...
2020-08-03  3          ...
...
2020-08-30  2          ...
2020-08-31  2          ...
2020-09-01  2          sum of 2020-09-01 to 2020-10-01
2020-09-02  1          ...
2020-09-03  2          ...
...
```

Base on Adrian's reply I'm trying to make it with sub selects like:

```
select
  (
    select
      sum(qq.value)
    from
      data_table qq
    where
      qq.date between date_trunc('month', q.date)
      and date_trunc('month', q.date) + interval '1 month'
  ) period_sum
, date
, value
from
  data_table q
```

But it's missing the first day of the next month. I think I need to tweak the `interval` part.

Comment: Are you expecting only sum? If not then add some sample output in question.

Comment: Only for Aug 2020 or all months?

Comment: Added output. All months!

Comment: `date_trunc('month', q.date) + interval '1 month'` gets you something like `11/01/2020 00:00:00 PDT` which will miss all the timestamps `> 00:00:00` on `11/01/2020`. You need to do something like 'date_trunc('month', q.date + interval '1 month') + interval '1 day' which gets you something like `11/02/2020 00:00:00 PST`. That will catch the timestamps in `'11/01/2020'`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver nice catch!

Comment: If you are going to a lot of this I would check out `range` types here [Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As example:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(VALUE)
FROM
    some_table
WHERE 
    Date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-09-01';
```

Comment: Mmmm, been thinking about window functions and this seems to be simple and fine. Will try with subselects (because I need this as a new column) and see how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a value per month.   Swap out your_table for your table name and your_date_field for whatever your date field is called.

**EDIT** Put the year bit in so you can run this over multiple years should you wish to.

```
SELECT 
   SUM(VALUE), 
   date_part('month', your_date_field ), 
   date_part('year', your_date_field )
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY 
  date_part('month', your_date_field ),
  date_part('year', your_date_field )
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! Note I need to sum the month and also the first day of the next month. Also, date_trunc('month', date_field) would be a way to make this just one line!